# Domain name masking for django webapp

Tags: django, apache, dns, saas, domain-masking

I have a website with the domain address: www.example.com. We are providing a SaaS solution.

The issue is we are facing a demand from some clients & that is domain name masking, i.e. the client wants to access my website from www.client1website.com & www.client2website.com & so on....

Is there any option that would be possible in Django? I dont want to change the Allowed Host thing as that would make the service non-scalable.

FYI: I am using Apache as of now & can also move to nginx of needed.

**Edit:1**

With some support from serverfault, I got the issue of domain name masking solved.

Now, this is a pure **Django** issue:

I have my original hostname as www.example.com which is masked my client's custom domain: www.client1website.com

My doubt is, does both of them need to be in the Allowed Host list, although this is just some domain masking. The issue is if we need to have all the domain names in the allowed_host list, then this solution is not scalable.

Comment: I think this question belongs on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Well, thanks. Shall post over there too.